# How to indicate that an object might not have a key in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, flowtype

In Flow, there is a difference between the following:

```js
type Obj1 = { foo?: number }
type Obj2 = { foo: ?number }
```

The first type says that the object might not have the key `foo`, but if it does then `foo` is guaranteed to be a number. The second type reverses this: `foo` is guaranteed to be on the object, but its value might be null.

Does Typescript differentiate between these two? From what I can tell, it only offers the syntax of the first type, but it means a mixture of the two: `foo` might not exist, and if it does it might be null or undefined.

Comment: `foo: ?number` is not valid syntax.

Comment: @SLaks it's a [maybe type](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/maybe/) in Flow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In TypeScript you would do it like this:

```
type Obj1 = { foo?: number }
type Obj2 = { foo: number | undefined }
```

Comment: ah, so there is no shorthand?

Comment: Nope, that's all there is.

Answer (score 1):

You can get similar behavior by utilizing aliases and generics:

```
type maybe<T> = T | undefined;

interface Obj {
  prop: maybe<number>
}
```

Or if you want to allow `null`

```
type maybe<T> = T | undefined | null;

interface Obj {
  prop: maybe<number>
}
```